# How to kill the wither?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and I had every achievement except for "The Beginning". Because I had just spawned The Wither. I tried going at it but every time I hit it, it just regenerated health. **How do I kill it?**

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until the wither completely regenerates ALL of it's health before you can attack it. Attack it before and it will just regenerate your damage done.